# SQL - Insert GUID in existing column in table using stored procedure/temp table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table in SQL server with multiple columns. A column named usertxt1 is NULL. I want to insert a NEWID() in this column based on the ID column in the table.

```
ID   Product   Price     Date     usertxt1
1      A        10     9/8/2017
2      A        15     9/7/2017
3      B        20     8/8/2017
4      B        25     8/9/2017
5      C        13     6/3/2017
```

What I have been able to accomplish till now : I ran an update statement to enter GUIDS in this table. This is the test database I'm working in. My question is : How do I insert these usertxt10 values in the prod database in the exact same table? Also going ahead, how do I make sure a NEWID() is created when a new row is created in the table? From what I was told by a friend some sort of temp table stored procedure should do the trick, but I haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: Your requirements are unclear. You need to provide existing table definitions. You need to clearly describe your requirements; "insert a NEWID() in this column based on another ID column" - is too vague. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Please also tell what you have tried so far as this is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Made changes to the post.

Comment: what is NEWID(), is this a function which returns the new ID for that column in particular row ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your sp as :

```
DECLARE @id INT
INSERT  INTO [YouTable]
        ( usertxt1 )
VALUES  ( NULL
          )
SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

UPDATE  [YouTable]
SET     usertxt1 = NEWID()
WHERE   Id = @id
```

Answer (score 0):

As per you ask, this could be one of the way you can proceed with.

```
IF Object_ID('tempdb..#temp_t') iS NOT NULL
drop table #temp_t
declare @table TABLE 
(
ID int,name varchar(10),
usertxt varchar(20)
)

insert into @table(ID,name) values(1,'AA')
insert into @table(ID,name) values(2,'BB')
```

Below logic you can include in a function

```
declare @rand INT,@count INT=1,@MAXCount INT=1

 select @MAXCount = count(ID) from @table
 while(@count<=@MAXCount)
 BEGIN

    select ID as iD,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by ID) as rownum INTO #temp_t 
    from @table
      update t set usertxt = 

          convert(varchar(3),t.ID)+
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ROUND(CONVERT(INT,RAND()*1000),4))
          from @table t join #temp_t tt on
          tt.ID=t.ID and rownum=@count
set @count+=1
 END

  select * from @table
```

Comment: Thanks but I have explained a bit more on the issue, not sure if this solution is correct. I will nonetheless give it a shot.